# How can i conditionally style a <li> in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app using a ul as a toolbar.  I want to have a style (selected) to apply to the page the user is on.

How can I do that?

This is what I have so far, but the selected style is hard coded and I'm also not sure how to know what page is selected.

```
      <ul>
        <li class="firstItem"><%= link_to "About", '/about' %></li>
        <li class="item"><%= link_to "Page1", '/page1' %></li>
        <li class="item selected" <%= link_to "Page2", '/page2' %></li>
        <li class="item"><%= link_to "Contact", '/contact' %></li>
        <li class="lastItem"><%= link_to "Blog", '/blog' %></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if each li is linked to different controller you can use `controller_name` to add or not the `selected` class

Here is an example from my app, it's in haml

```
  %ul
    %li
      %a{:href => '/kebabs', :class => ('current' if controller_name == 'kebabs')} Admin kebabs
    %li
      %a{:href => '/statistics', :class => ('current' if controller_name == 'statistics')} Statistiques
    %li
      %a{:href => '/people', :class => ('current' if controller_name == 'people')} Admin Personnes
```

cheers

Comment: I think that will work.  I haven't seen the %ul %a markup before, though, what is that called so I can look into it more?

Comment: visit http://haml-lang.com/ ... much better than erb, well, that's my point of view ;o)

Answer (score 9):

I agree totally with Jarrod's advice, but just in case you encounter the need to process additional conditions (and want to avoid ugly embedded ruby in your HTML code), take a look at Rails' content_tag method.

With it, you can replace something like:

```
<li class=<%= @post.active? ? 'active' : 'suspended' %>>
  <%= link_to @post.name, post_path(@post) %>
</li>
```

With something like:

```
<%= content_tag :li, link_to(@post.name, post_path(@post), :class => @post.active? ? 'active' : 'suspended' %>
```

And of course, sticking this code into a helper and calling it from there will earn you more elegance-points.

Hope this helps.

PS: This is my first post on Stackoverflow, please be gentle. :)

Comment: Nice!  I was wanting to be able to create an li tag and use the :class => syntax, but didn't know how to do it.  That's great

Answer (score 1):

You can also use css for this. Give each the body each page a class and id from your controller and action names.

```
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>" id="<%= controller.action_name %>">
```

Then give your ul and li elements an id.

```
<ul id="nav'>
  <li id="about"></li>
  <li id="contact"></li>
  <li id="blog"></li>
</ul>
```

Now you can reference a specific link on a specific page from your stylesheet.

```
body.blog#index ul#nav a#blog:link
```

So if you want to make section links 'sticky' you can reference them all at once, leaving out the body id.

```
body.blog ul#nav a#blog:link,
body.contact ul#nav a#contact:link {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Check out more on CSS selectors.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/17/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)